# Setting up development environment for Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, development-environment, raspberry-pi, beagleboard

Lately I've decided to jump on the minicomputer "bandwagon" out of curiosity. I bought a pair of Raspberry Pi and BeagleBoard since they were both so cheap I couldn't resist :) but here is where my problems start. I had an idea for these devices before I bought them of course (console app). I set them up to my router so they could be accessible "installed" raspbian for the RPi and ubuntu arm for the BeagleBoard and installed and here is where my headache begins.

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop (dualboot) so that I would have access to an ARM compiler. Now before I proceed further I must tell you that I develop mainly in Windows environment but I'm familiar with linux because of my sysadmin background. Anyhow, because I don't have much free time after work since I like to meet up friends and family, I like to be able to modify my source and cross compile under the Windows (Visual Studio Ultimate 2012) at work when I feel free or I need to relax, under the Ubuntu on my laptop when I actually find the time and I want to have a simple procedure to compile for ARM on my laptop and have the binaries sent to the RPi and the BeagleBoard (even if manually) as well as compiling for x86 on Windows and Linux so that I could after all debug my code.

I read around how other people are doing it and I went with Eclipse CDT as my linux IDE+Compiler(g++/gdb) and with Visual Studio under windows. Made my own directory structure but I find the Makefile requirement EXTREMELY tedious. It took me days to get into that thing and I am still not satisfied with it, being used to simple F5 under windows to get Build + Run Debug, all that beign well structured the way I want it.

Anyhow all went well at first, following the C++11 "standard" and adding the appropriate flags under linux for it and then some weird errors started to show up, I couldn't even compile SQLite while this thing has been running perfectly under windows/visual studio. After few days of trial and error I gave up and I come here, asking for an advice

How do you guys, RPi/BeagleBoard fans work with those computers, how do you set up multi-OS/multi-Arch environment for debugging and compiling? I find it extremely difficult to the point that I'm considering using Java just so I could get my idea running :< . One way is to have all the libraries and compilers on the device itself and carry it around which is no problem as well but It does feel a bit medieval and after all the SD cards that I have are quite limited in size, having OS on them.

Any tips, links to guides, books are more than welcome. Even though English is not my mother's tongue, I don't mind reading books/articles in it.

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I carry the project around in a thumb drive.

Comment: Less storytelling, more questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't bet on being able to cross-compile for `linux-arm` or `linux-x86` targets from a Windows host, so the rest of my advices are for your Ubuntu box only.

---

Concerning Ubuntu for ARM on your BeagleBoard, as long as it uses one of the Debian `armel/armhf` architectures then you can just install an `emdebian` cross-toolchain along with `xapt`. There are plenty of short and easy tutorials out there, pick the one you want.

---

Now the problem with Raspbian is that it doesn't use the usual `armel/armhf` architectures from Debian but is somewhere in the middle (hard-float ARMv6, while `armel` is for soft-float ARMv5 and `armhf` is for hard-float ARMv7). So you can't use the standard `emdebian` cross-toolchains along with `xapt` to cross-compile for Raspbian.

There is an official Raspbian cross-toolchain though, you may want to [read that tutorial](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/) (but IMHO you should forget about Eclipse, it's overkill, any text editor like `kate` or `gedit` will be much less confusing for small projects).

---

> I find the Makefile requirement EXTREMELY tedious

You can use **autotools** to generate the `configure`, `Makefile` etc, it will be much easier than writing a bare `Makefile` by yourself. See eg. [this tutorial](http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/automake/automake.shtml).

---

> have the binaries sent to the RPi and the BeagleBoard

Two words: SSH / SCP. And yes, you can easily script that and make it part of your build process.

---

Last but not least, I mean no offense (I went through that too ;)) but since you're a Windows developer who has little to no experience about how to develop on Linux my best advice would be to drop the whole cross-compilation stuff for now, until you are really used to Linux development. Linux development is confusing at first, cross-compiling is also confusing at first, no need to handle both at the same time.

An easy thing to do is to have your toolchain and code on the target box (RPi/Beagle), mount your source directory through SSHFS/whatever so that you can edit it comfortably from your main machine, and compile inside a SSH session. You don't even need to have the target box physically available as long as you can reach it through the network/internet (assuming it is correctly secured).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the long and thoughtful answer. I basically picked Eclipse CDT because it "reminds" me of Visual Studio with its Debug workspace. I guess I have some more reading to do on linux developer toolchain. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Well, IDEs vs (plain text editors + command line) is quite a personal taste/habit. If Eclipse suits you, go along with it, the main goal after all is to minimize confusion and have an easier learning curve. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your build process is very complicated so don't expect any easy solutions. You are trying to use several operating systems and compilers and target architectures. [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) was created to help with this kind of thing but it is **not** an easy solution. I don't think there is one.

Comment: Well, okay ... how are other people doing it. Is everybody adding the compilers/libraries to their Rpi/BB :O I will certainly dig into CMake. The MySQL C++ Connector requires it so I suppose it is powerful for that but more opinions are always welcome! P.S: I guess I can get out of all this with ARM emulator but I don't know any cross-platform one